# About the covariant derivative - is this correct?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curves

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be a regular surface, the image of a parametrization $X: U \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \to S$ and $\alpha:I \to W \subset S$ be a curve in $S$. We can write $\alpha(t) = X(u(t), v(t))$, then the covariant derivative of $\alpha'$ at some $t \in I$ is given by:

$$\begin{align}
\dfrac{\sf D\alpha'}{{\rm{d}}t} &=  {\rm proj}_{T_{\large\alpha(t)}S} \ \alpha''(t) \\
&= \alpha''(t) - \langle\alpha''(t), N(u(t), v(t)) \rangle N(u(t), v(t))
\end{align}$$

Is this correct? If not, what am I getting wrong?

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression I wrote is correct.